# Como buscar diferentes extensões de arquivos

Tags: python, regex

Estou procurando uns arquivos com o final .jar, .py e .sh, porém só quando coloco um deles o código roda.

`finded = re.findall(r'\w*.jar\b'|'\w*.sh\b'|'\w*.py\b', text)`

Mensagem de erro:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Dica: a conjugação de _to find_ no pretérito é _found_ e não _finded_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é necessário repetir a regex inteira. No caso do seu código nem faz sentido, porque você está tentando "combinar" várias strings com o operador `|` e Python não aceita este tipo de construção até onde eu sei.

O que você precisa é usar estes operadores para combinar diferentes padrões aceitos na regex.

Uma regex que funciona seria: `\w*\.(jar|sh|py)\b`, onde:

- `\w`: Qualquer caracter
- `*`: Zero ou mais do padrão anterior
- `\.`: Encontra o literal para ponto
- `(jar|sh|py)`: Encontra um dos literais (jar ou sh ou py)

```py
import re
found = re.findall(r'(\w*\.(jar|sh|py)\b)', 'teste.jar script.sh program.exe script.bat')
print(found) # [('teste.jar', 'jar'), ('script.sh', 'sh')]
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso545628)

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro veja bem o que você fez. Você criou três strings e colocou `|` entre elas:

```py
     finded = re.findall(r'\w*.jar\b'|'\w*.sh\b'|'\w*.py\b', text)
#                         ^         ^ ^        ^ ^        ^
     #                    |         | |        | |        |
     #                    |         | |        | |        |
# aqui começa a           |         | |        | |        \__ aqui termina a terceira string
# primeira string ________/         | |        | |
     #                              | |        | |
     #                              | |        | |
     #                              | |        | \__ aqui começa a terceira string
     #                              | |        |
     #                              | |        \__ aqui termina a segunda string
     #                              | |        
# aqui termina a primeira string ___/ \___ aqui começa a segunda string
```

Ou seja, você está tentando fazer `string | outra_string | e_mais_outra_string`. Só que o `|` não é um operador válido para strings, daí o erro.

Para resolver bastaria eliminar as aspas do meio, deixando tudo em uma única string:

```py
re.findall(r'\w*.jar\b|\w*.sh\b|\w*.py\b', text)
```

Mas tem muita redundância aí. Você pode fazer como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/545629/112052) (`(\w*.(jar|sh|py)\b)`), mas eu sugiro algumas alterações:

- `\w*` significa "*zero ou mais letras, dígitos ou `_`*". Isso quer dizer que se o nome do arquivo for apenas `.jar`, será aceito (pois tem zero caracteres antes do ponto). Você pode trocar para `\w+` (uma ou mais ocorrências), pois aí garante que deve ter pelo menos um caractere antes do ponto (a menos, é claro, que você queira mesmo pegar nomes como `.jar`)
- O ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere ([exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), então se quiser somente o caractere `.`, tem que ser `\.`
- os parênteses formam grupos de captura, e quando estes estão presentes, `findall` retorna todos os grupos. No caso, a extensão está em um grupo, então além do nome do arquivo, será retornado também a extensão separadamente. Mas se quer apenas os nomes dos arquivos, pode trocar para [grupos de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), usando `(?:` em vez de apenas `(`

Ou seja:

```py
import re

text = 'abc.txt def.jar g123.sh aaa.c xyz.py'
arquivos = re.findall(r'\w+\.(?:jar|sh|py)\b', text)
print(arquivos) # ['def.jar', 'g123.sh', 'xyz.py']
```

---

Indo um pouco além, nomes de arquivos não se resumem a letras, números e `_` (que é o que o `\w` reconhece). Podemos ter nomes como `abc-def-1.0.15.tar.gz` e até mesmo nomes com espaços. Neste caso, o `\w` não é suficiente, e teria que ser algo assim:

```py
import re

# o nome com espaços tem \ antes do espaço para diferenciar do espaço que separa dois arquivos
text = r'abc-def-1.0.15.jar nome\ com\ espaços.sh'
arquivos = re.findall(r'\b(?:[\w\-.]|\\ )+\.(?:jar|sh|py)\b', text)
print(arquivos) # encontra os dois arquivos
```

Ou seja, agora antes da extensão o nome pode ter `\w` (letras, números e `_`), hífen e ponto, além de espaços (desde que seja escapado por `\`).

Mas enfim, já estamos indo além da pergunta, foi só para mostrar que regex não é algo "mágico", e que quanto mais complicados os casos, pior ela vai ficando.

Por fim, se estiver fazendo a busca no sistema de arquivos (pois não é dito de onde vem o `text`), [tem maneiras melhores de resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3964681).

Answer (score -1):

consegui alterando dessa forma:

found = re.findall(r'\w*.jar\b|\w*.sh\b|\w*.py\b', text)

já estou aprendendo inglês junto, troquei o nome da variável tb!

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).